# C# What's the difference between (int x, int) vs (int, int)

Tags: c#

For example, in return type or argument type of a method.
`(int x, int)` vs `(int, int)`

Comment: So you are asking about the difference between `(int x, int)` and `(int, int)`?

Comment: are you familiar with tuples? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: ermm i think that's just a named tuple, the x i mean

Comment: @Sweeper that's correct. @keys! if you could post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @sommmen that helps a lot. with the example and all, if you could extract a summary, I'll accept your answer too

Comment: @Xeuron but you can't accept two answers at the same time 

Comment: @Sweeper may the first / best answer win haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Tuple types (C# reference)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

> (double, int) t1 = (4.5, 3); Console.WriteLine($"Tuple with elements
> {t1.Item1} and {t1.Item2}."); // Output: // Tuple with elements 4.5
> and 3.
>
> (double Sum, int Count) t2 = (4.5, 3); Console.WriteLine($"Sum of
> {t2.Count} elements is {t2.Sum}."); // Output: // Sum of 3 elements is
> 4.5.

**Your code:**

```
public static implicit operator (int x, int)(Point point) 

public static implicit operator (int, int)(Point point)
```

The difference is that one of the tuple variable is named and could later be called with `t1.x` instead of `t1.Item1`

Comment: Thanks, I accepted ASAP. Would you mind upvoting the question?